# Sources on evolution of submanifolds subject to Ricci flow

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I am seeking any textbook or paper addressing the evolution of submanifolds of a manifold undergoing Ricci Flow.  Please, any pointer towards this topic is more than welcome.

This old MO post may be relevant:
[How submanifolds evolve under Ricci flow?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121122/how-submanifolds-evolve-under-ricci-flow)

Comment: I made some edits to your post in an attempt to improve it. Feel free to re-edit or undo my edits if you want to.

Comment: Thanks Joonas Ilmavirta, all corrections are good for me.